# NotificationManager Error in Android - Bad Notification

Tags: android, notificationmanager

Here is the code,
where cb is checkbox:

```
cb1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if(cb1.isChecked()){
                builder=new NotificationCompat.Builder(Main2Activity.this);
                builder.setContentTitle(arrayList.get(3)+" V/s "+arrayList.get(4));
                builder.setContentText(arrayList.get(1)+"\n"+arrayList.get(2));
                builder.setAutoCancel(true);
                builder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.baali);
                notificationManager=(NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
                notificationManager.notify(0,builder.build());
            }
        }
    });
```

and the Error is:

> android.app.RemoteServiceException: Bad notification posted from package xyz.abc: Couldn't expand RemoteViews for: StatusBarNotification(pkg=xyz.abc user=UserHandle{0} id=1 tag=null score=0: Notification(pri=0 contentView=xyz.abc/0x1090064 vibrate=null sound=null defaults=0x0 flags=0x10 kind=[null]))

Comment: possibly notification ID can't be 0. Try using other ID.